# Powershell encrypt and PHP decrypt string issue

Tags: php, powershell, encryption, encoding

Trying to send information from PowerShell to PHP.
The code provided here is not for production, but simply to illustrate my problem and asking for help.

When encrypting text in PowerShell and decrypting it in PHP I get the correct text back, but it is formatted wrong. Here the end result:

[image: TestString wrong format]

I believe it has to do with encoding, but I know am not sure and have therefore no idea on how to fix this.
Any hint or solution is highly appreciated.

Here are the two simplified *test* scripts.

PowerShell - Encryption

```
Function EncryptString {
    Param ([string]$inputStr)

    $inputBytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($inputStr)
    $enc = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8

    $AES = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.AESManaged
    $iv = "&9*zS7LY%ZN1thfI"
    $AES.Mode = [System.Security.Cryptography.CipherMode]::CBC
    #$AES.Padding = [System.Security.Cryptography.PaddingMode]::Zeros
    $AES.BlockSize = 128
    $AES.KeySize = 256
    $AES.IV = $enc.GetBytes($iv)
    $AES.Key = $enc.GetBytes($script:passKey)

    $encryptor = $AES.CreateEncryptor()

    $encryptedBytes = $encryptor.TransformFinalBlock($inputBytes, 0, $inputBytes.length)
    $output = [Convert]::ToBase64String($encryptedBytes)

    return $output
}



$passkey = "12345678901234567890123456789012"

$txtTemp = EncryptString "TestString"
Write-host $txtTemp
```

PHP - Decryption

```
<?php

$iv = "&9*zS7LY%ZN1thfI";
$passKey = "12345678901234567890123456789012";

$txtTemp ="N/l69qyZqPyWRTDWLCQBtA==";

$cipher = "aes-256-cbc";
$returnStr = openssl_decrypt($txtTemp, $cipher, $passKey, $options=OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING, $iv);
echo $returnStr."<br/>";

?>
```

Comment: You need to specify PKCS7padding (some implementations call it PKCS5padding), not zero padding. What you're seeing are the padding bytes that should have been stripped off by the encryptor.

Comment: @PresidentJamesMoveonPolk Probably better posted as an answer. Yes, it is one of those errors that keep coming back, but if you're rep hunting you'd better skip the encryption / cryptography tags entirely. So let us compensate ourselves :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are seeing padding bytes which are used to make the AES input length a multiple of the block size.

The (misleadingly named) `OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING` option means "no padding at all", i.e. add no padding before encrypting and remove no padding after decrypting.

Remove the option to have openssl_decrypt strip the PKCS#5/7 padding bytes.

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing are the padding bytes from the PKCS7 padding applied by AesManaged class. That is the default. It is also the default for PHP openssl_encrypt and openssl_decrypt. So stick with the defaults.